# Cannot resolve method putObject on AWSS3bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have used this code

```
      @Override
    public UploadResponse upload(MultipartFile audio) throws IOException {
        var fileName = audio.getOriginalFilename();
        var inputFileStream = audio.getInputStream();
        var size = audio.getSize();
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, "");
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputFileStream, tempFile);
        InputStream in = FileUtils.openInputStream(tempFile);
        uploadToS3(fileName, in, size);
        return null;
    }

    private void uploadToS3(String fileName, InputStream in, long size) {
            var putObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key(fileName).build();
            var requestBody = RequestBody.fromInputStream(in, size);
           this.s3client.putObject(putObjectRequest, requestBody);
        }
```

It is handling for upload mp3 or mp4 from Multipart API to AWS s3bucket. but when I use this method I got an error that cannot resolve the `putObject` Method. for handle this code I use dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
          <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
          <version>1.11.133</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
          <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
          <version>2.17.23</version>
        </dependency>
```

My question is what is exactly problem from my code ?

Comment: what is the definition for s3client? Possibly not defined or typo there

Answer (score 0):

You have both version 1 and version 2 of the Java SDK imported into the project. Both SDKs are very similar and have objects with same names. Most probably you imported the Request class from one version and the Client class from the another one.

SDK versions 1 and 2 can coexist in the same project, but they are not compatible and you should avoid having both of them in the classpath. Import only the needed package (for example S3 package), never the "whole SDK".

Both versions of SDK are maintained by AWS. By now (Sep. 2021) there are only few advantages using the version 2. See links:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/migration.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/migration-side-by-side.html